# Show 404 page not found

Tags: angularjs, express

Using `ui-router` in Angularjs users can accesses `resources` from my DB with a unique code in the URL like this:

```
http://example.com/abc123
```

with the state:

```
.state('show', {
    url: '/:resourceID',
    templateUrl: '/views/resource.html',
    controller: 'ResourceController'
})
```

However, I'm not sure how to render the 404.html when a `resource` isn't found in the DB. At the moment I am returning a 404 error from Expressjs and I have an interceptor that then redirects using:

```
//detect 404 and redirect url
$window.location.href = "/error/404";
```

but this isn't ideal - you have to wait for the redirect and the URL changes.

How can I show a static 404.html and not affect the URL in the browser?

Comment: please check for the folder structure. i guess templateUrl: 'views/resource.html'

Comment: if you don't want url to change can't you just send back an empty array and if no array length show directive with your 404 template?

Comment: @charlietfl - sorry I don't understand your comment - could you explain

Comment: @AdityaSethi `resource.html` is the template for the resource not the 404

Comment: within resource.html have something like: `<div ng-if ="!scopeResources.length" my404Directive>`

Comment: Ok this is a workaround but is there no way to show the static 404.html that resides in the same folder as the index.html page?